# Equivalent of Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product in apt or dpkg?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, apt, dpkg

I'm using the following command in Powershell to see what versions of programs are installed.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Select-Object -Property Name, version
```

Is there an equivalent to this in `apt` or `dpkg` in Debian/Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

On Debian-descended systems (Ubuntu, etc…) you can just do

```
dpkg --list
```

to show all applications installed via the apt system.

```
cory@redbarchetta[13:40:26]~$ dpkg --list
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                       Version                                     Architecture Description
+++-==========================================-===========================================-============-=========================================>
ii  accountsservice                            0.6.55-0ubuntu12~20.04.4                    amd64        query and manipulate user account informa>
ii  accountsservice-ubuntu-schemas             0.0.7+17.10.20170922-0ubuntu1               all          AccountsService schemas for Ubuntu
ii  acl                                        2.2.53-6                                    amd64        access control list - utilities
ii  acpi-support                               0.143                                       amd64        scripts for handling many ACPI events
ii  acpid                                      1:2.0.32-1ubuntu1                           amd64        Advanced Configuration and Power Interfac>
ii  adduser                                    3.118ubuntu2                                all          add and remove users and groups
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it through `grep-status`.

Install `dctrl-tools`

```
sudo apt install dctrl-tools
```

Then:

```
grep-status -sPackage,Version -n "install ok installed"
```